# Show results using tabs and accordions

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 tables (`posts`, `categories`), There is one to many relation between both tables(each category could contain more that one post).

```
                     posts table
___________________________________________________
|    |       |         |             |             |  
| id | title | content | category_id | posts_order |                                        
|____|_______|_________|_____________|_____________|
|    |       |         |             |             |    
| 1  | test1 | testing |     1       |       0     |   
|____|_______|_________|_____________|_____________|
|    |       |         |             |             |    
| 2  | test2 | testing |     1       |       1     |   
|____|_______|_________|_____________|_____________|
|    |       |         |             |             |    
| 3  | test3 | testing |     2       |       2     |   
|____|_______|_________|_____________|_____________|
|    |       |         |             |             |    
| .  | ..... | ....... |     .       |       .     |   
|____|_______|_________|_____________|_____________|


       categories table
___________________________
|      |        |         |  
| c_id | c_name | c_order |                                       
|______|________|_________|
|      |        |         |   
|   1  |  cat1  |    0    |      
|______|________|_________|            
|   2  |  cat2  |    1    |      
|______|________|_________|
|      |        |         |       
|   3  |  cat3  |    2    |      
|______|________|_________|   
| .    | ..... | .......  |      
|______|_______|__________|
```

There is a relation(one-to-many), Using `id` from posts and `c_id` from categories.

I want to show the categories in tabs, then inside each tab there will be the related posts:

```
________________________________________
|                 |          |          |
|    cat1         |   cat2   |   cat3   |
|  (active)       |__________|__________|
|                                       |
|                                       |
|    test1                              |
|        testing                        |
|                                       |
|    test2                              |
|        testing                        |
|_______________________________________|
```

So for example if the first tab is active, The related posts from `cat1`, Which are `test1` and `test2` should be shown with there content as an accordion.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `categories` LEFT JOIN `posts` ON categories.c_id = posts.id order by categories.c_order ASC
```

Then print that data to the tabs and accordion:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <?php foreach ($results as $result) { ?>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#<?php echo $result['c_name'] ?>" aria-controls="<?php echo $result['c_name'] ?>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                <?php echo $result['c_name'] ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?> //end foreach
</ul> <!-- Nav tabs -->

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <?php foreach ($results as $result) { ?>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="<?php echo $result['c_name'] ?>">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true"> 
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php echo $result['id']; ?>_post" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                <?php echo $result['title'] ?>
                            </a>
                        </h4> <!-- .panel-title  -->
                    </div> <!-- .panel-heading  -->
                    <div id="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>_post" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <?php echo $result['content']; ?>
                        </div> <!-- .panel-body  -->
                    </div> <!-- .panel-collapse  -->
                </div> <!-- .panel  -->
            </div> <!-- .panel-group  -->
        </div> <!-- .tab-pane  -->
    <?php } ?> //end foreach
</div> <!-- end Tab panes -->
```

So that I should get 3 tabs, Each tab contains each category posts and content.

But if I have 3 `categories` and 9 `posts` for example, I get 9 tabs, Each tab contains 1 post or no posts at all.

Is there is a problem with the query?

Should I change the `foreach` places?

Comment: Can you show how you're fetching the results and populating the `$results` array?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I'm using PDO, `$results = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM categories LEFT JOIN posts ON categories.c_id = posts.id order by categories.c_order ASC'); $results->execute();
$results = $results->fetchAll();`

Comment: Then I use `foreach` 2 times, The first one is to print the categories inside the `<ul>` `<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
   <?php foreach ($results as $result) { ?>
     <li role="presentation" ><a href="#<?php echo $result['c_name'] ?>" aria-controls="<?php echo $result['c_name'] ?>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $result['c_name'] ?></a></li>
 <?php } ?>
  </ul>`

Comment: The 2nd time to print the data  inside `<div class="tab-content">`

Comment: I can't print the 2nd `foreach` is the code is too long, But it's included in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `$results = $results->fetchAll();` you can fetch the rows one at a time and group them by category as you go.

```
while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $categories[$row['c_name']][] = $row;
}
```

Then loop to print the tabs can be like this:

```
// for the tabs, you just need the keys (the distinct categories)
foreach (array_keys($categories) as $category_name) { ...
```

And for the tab content:

```
// the tab panes
foreach ($categories as $category_name => $posts) {
    // accordion container
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        // individual accordion panels
```

I didn't include the markup so as not to obscure the logic. If you have trouble seeing how to integrate it into your markup, let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: It's working, But I have to click on the tab to see the related data, As you see there are more that one tab, So I use jQuery to add the class `active` to the first tab, It becomes active, But I can't see the data when I refresh the page, I have to go to another tab then return to see the data

Comment: jQuery: `$('.nav-tabs li').first().addClass('active');`

Comment: I fixed that by adding `$('.tab-content .tab-pane').first().addClass('active');`